# Display full URL to uploaded image with echo statement

Tags: php, upload, echo

I found a upload script that is perfect for needs as it renames images [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9906-PHP-Validate-and-process-an-uploaded-file-.html).

Works great but need to modify so it displays the full URL to image after uploaded.

Have working to some extent but stuck and need input.

My mod to the above referenced script:

```
$url  = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        echo dirname(dirname($url)).$uploadResult;
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<a href='$uploadResult' target='_blank'><img src='$uploadResult' alt='picture'></a><br/>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<form><input name='imgcode' size='60' type='text' value='$uploadResult' /></form>";
        echo "<br />";
```

Above outputs like this:

[image]

**The issue I have is**: need to remove the .. from path (../images/01092016211821.gif)

Have explored and attempted the str_replace function but cannot get working.

Would also like to echo the full image URL path inside input area to make copying easy.

Thanks in advance for advice/solution.

Here is full script...

example.php:

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST["Send"])){      // If form is submited
        require_once("uploadClass.php");    
        $file=$_FILES["fileField"];                 // Get file from form

        $destination="../images/";
        if (!file_exists($destination)) {       // If 'destination' folder dosn't exist, create
            mkdir($destination);
        }

        $process=new Upload($destination);      // Set 'destination' as new default destination folder for upload

        $uploadResult=$process->executeUpload($file);   // Attach file to upload process

        $url  = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        echo dirname(dirname($url)).$uploadResult;
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<a href='$uploadResult' target='_blank'><img src='$uploadResult' alt='picture'></a><br/>";
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<form><input name='imgcode' size='60' type='text' value='{dirname(dirname($url).$uploadresult)}' /></form>";
        echo "<br />";
        }
?>

<form action="?" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="dyntable" class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>
                File
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" placeholder="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <center>
                    <button type="submit" name="Send">Send</button>
                    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

uploadClass.php:

```
<?php
    /// Classe d'upload de uploaded_file
    class Upload{
        protected $destination="Img/Uploads/";  //Default destination folder
        protected $max_file_size=7500000;       //Max file size
        protected $authorized_extensions=array('png','jpg','gif','bmp','jpeg','pdf','word','txt');      //Authorised file extensions

        public function __construct($dest=null,$types=null){
            $this->setParameters($dest,$types);
        }

        // Set general parameters
        public function setParameters($dest=null,$types=null){
            if($dest!=null && $dest!=""){
                $this->destination=$dest;
            }
            if($types!=null && $types!=""){
                $this->authorized_extensions=$type;
            }
        }

        // Return uploaded file path or errorMessages list
        public function executeUpload($uploaded_file,$destination=null){
            if($destination==null || $destination==""){
                $destination=$this->destination;
            }
            if (!file_exists($destination)) {       // If 'destination' folder dosn't exist, create
                mkdir($destination);
            }

            $i=0;
            $errorMessage="";
            $errorMessage1="";
            $errorMessage2="";
            if (!empty($uploaded_file)){    //If existing file is really submited
                //On vérifie si la taille du uploaded_file envoyé est acceptable
                $file_size = $uploaded_file['size'];
                if ( $file_size > $this->max_file_size )
                {
                    $errorMessage = "File too heavy. Current max file size is : ".$this->max_file_size;
                    return "";
                }

                //On définit les variables :
                $extensions_valides = $this->authorized_extensions; //Liste des extensions valides
                if ($uploaded_file['errorMessage'] > 0)
                {
                    $i++;
                    $errorMessage = "File transfert failed";
                }

                $extension_upload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($uploaded_file['name'], '.')  ,1)); //Get uploaded_file extension
                if (!in_array($extension_upload,$extensions_valides) )
                {
                    $i++;
                    $errorMessage2 = "Extension forbidden";
                }
            }
            //echo $errorMessage2;

            if ($i == 0) // If any errorMessage have been detected
            {
                if (isset($uploaded_file['size']))
                {
                    //Move the uploaded_file to the desired place
                    $ico="chaine";
                    $horodatage=date("dmYHis");
                    $nomico = str_replace(' ','',$ico).".".$extension_upload;
                    $ico = $destination.str_replace(' ','',$horodatage).".".$extension_upload;
                    move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file['tmp_name'],$ico);

                    return $ico;
                }else{
                    return NULL;
                }
            }else{
                echo "<h3>Upload failed</h3>";
                echo "<table><tr><td> <b><u>Cause(s) :</u></b></td></tr><tr><td>";
                echo $errorMessage.'<br>';
                echo $errorMessage1.'<br>';
                echo $errorMessage2.'<br>';
                echo "</td></tr></table>";
                //return "0";
                return NULL;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

**My Solution based on input from @Forbs response:**

```
<?php   
    if(isset($_POST["Send"])){      // If form is submited
        require_once("uploadClass.php");    
        $file=$_FILES["fileField"];                 // Get file from form

        $destination="../images/";
        if (!file_exists($destination)) {       // If 'destination' folder dosn't exist, create
            mkdir($destination);
        }

        $process=new Upload($destination);      // Set 'destination' as new default destination folder for upload

        $uploadResult=$process->executeUpload($file);   // Attach file to upload process

        $url  = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
        $url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
        $url .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        if (substr($uploadResult,0,2) == "..")
        $uploadResult = substr($uploadResult,2);

        echo dirname(dirname($url)).$uploadResult;
        echo "<br />";
        echo "<br />";

        }
?>

<form action="?" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="dyntable" class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>
                File
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" placeholder="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <center>
                    <button type="submit" name="Send">Send</button>
                    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<textarea id="myText" rows="3" cols="80"><?php echo dirname(dirname($url)).$uploadResult; ?></textarea>
```

Solves my issue good enough to finish project.

Comment: What did you have done to achieve this ? Can you show us your code please.

Comment: @tanaydin with me being new wasn't sure if should just provide link to the upload script or paste it all in. Is link not good way to show script @ http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9906-PHP-Validate-and-process-an-uploaded-file-.html

Comment: My bad @tanaydin Did not know users had to be registered / logged in at phpclasses site. Added entire script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1) Remove the leading two periods if they appear right?

```
 if (substr($uploadresult,0,2) == "..")
    $uploadresult = substr($uploadresult,2);
```

## 2) why not change the input to

value ='{dirname(dirname($url).$uploadresult)}' to solve that?

Comment: 1) Yes, remove the two periods. Like to strip them out so not appear in URL. Just not positive where to place code you recommend. 2) When adding recommended value I get: {dirname(dirname(http://myurl.net/testbed/AdminLTE/upload/?).)}

Comment: Thanks @Forbs! Your input got me going. Had to make a few changes like $uploadresult to $uploadResult. Accepting your answer.